# Maven put .jar file in the wrong directory

Tags: maven, jna

My project runs on JAVA 8. In JAVA 8 is no method to remove the file or directory into recycle bin.
I found JNA library with the method .moveToTrash() which works great if I run my project from IDE. But I need to deploy my project with Ant and when Ant builds my project  I get the error:
"package com.sun.jna.platform does not exist". So, if I go to:
.m2\repository\com\sun I see no jna directory and jna .jar located in a completely different directory:
.m2\repository\net\java\dev\jna\jna-platform\5.7.0\jna-platform-5.7.0.jar!\com\sun\jna\platform\FileUtils.class
Why is the import of this dependency called from a folder that does not exist and how to ensure that both the import and .jar are in the same directory?
Dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
  <artifactId>jna-platform</artifactId>
  <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
File file = new File("C:\\Slides\\dog.jpg");
com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils fileUtils = com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils.getInstance();
try {
    fileUtils.moveToTrash(new File[] { file });
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
}
```

I have tried using JNA .jar libraries without Maven but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The download folders and the packages have nothing to do with each other. This is not the reason for your problem.

The real problem is: You did not build an executable JAR. JARs do not contain (or find) their dependencies unless you build them with the Maven shade plugin or Maven assembly plugin.

Comment: Thank you. 
I will definitely try Maven Shade and describe the result in detail.